# Let $A$ and $B$ be nonnegattive matrices. What is the rank of $I + A^T A$, where $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix with non-negative eigenvalues. What is the rank of $I + A^T A$?

Comment: What does $B$ have to do with the question ?

Comment: What do you mean by nonnegative matrices? Are entries of $A$ and $B$ nonnegative?

Comment: Yes, also that what do you mean by non-negative.

Comment: my bad, B has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: non negative matrix means that its eigenvalues are non negative

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the unnecessary parts. Please let me know if you feel I have changed the intended question.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is $m\times n$ and $x\in\mathbb R^n$, then 
$$
x^T(I+A^TA)x=x^Tx+x^TA^TAx=x^Tx+(Ax)^TAx\geq x^Tx. 
$$
It follows that if $(I+A^TA)x=0$, then $x^Tx=0$, so $x=0$. That is, $I+A^TA$ is injective, so its rank is $n$.

There is no need to restrict the possible eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

So if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$ is of rank $r$, where $1 \leq r \leq min(M,N)$, then $A^T A$ is also of rank $r$.

Therefore, $I + A^TA$ is necessarily of rank $N$, since $\lambda_{min}(I + A^TA) \geq 1$.